# Understanding on installing packages using npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I just started to use npm command while learning angularJS2. I get errors while trying to install packages using npm command, for instance when i try to run this command

```
npm install json-typescript-mapper --save
```

to install json to typescript mapper package, i am not able to install it. am i missing something, should i change the registry? my current registry is **http://registry.npmjs.org/** should i have to change the registry inorder to install the package

**ERROR**

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

and after that when i try to import the package, i get an error stating the package not found because the package was not added

Comment: *"I get errors while trying to install packages"* - what errors?

Comment: i have updated the error, we have to change the registry,isnt it? ogtherwise how the npm knows from where to pick the files, right !

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings. They shouldn't cause the install to fail. Unless you have a specific reason to, you shouldn't change the registry.

Comment: ok could you help me understand how npm gets this file, because the registry which i have is something different then the source from which the file is getting downloaded